# WebService Spring doesn't initialize bean for service and consumer

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-services, soap

I am creating a webService Spring with SOAP and i have a trouble. At beginning i had done a webapp with Spring MVC with service and consumer (spring Data and spring JDBC) where the interface is exposed and it's work. So i suppose the trouble doesn't come from these modules.

But now, i want to reuse my service and consumer for my webService and it doesn't work. I have done a new archetype with maven, add many dependency and if i don't use my service or consumer (webService alone), i can use SOAPUI and return a string.

However, once i try to connect my service and my consumer, my TomCat log tell me dependency is unsatisfied for my injection... I don't understand why...

PS: i have done some copy paste from my webapp MVC to my webService and i am a beginner in java.

TomCat Localhost Log :

> 10-Jan-2019 04:28:11.625 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>   10-Jan-2019 04:28:11.645 INFOS [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>   10-Jan-2019 04:28:16.754 GRAVE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'borrowingServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'borrowingRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'p3.repository.BorrowingRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <groupId>p3</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <artifactId>webService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>webService</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <!--<url>http://www.example.com</url>-->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- tools de génération WS pour OS Linux et Max -->
        <tool.wsgen>${java.home}/../bin/wsgen</tool.wsgen>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- ===== Modules ===== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p3</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p3</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.ha/ha-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
            <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- La dépendance vers commons-lang3 est exclue -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- deriver MySql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bval</groupId>
            <artifactId>bval-jsr</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                <!--<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2-kernel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                                <wsdlOptions>
                                    <wsdlOption>
                                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    </wsdlOption>
                                </wsdlOptions>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sun-jax</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sun-jax</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Déclaration d'une session d'envoi de mail accessible en JNDI pour les logs cf. scr/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml -->
<resource-ref>
    <description>Session d'envoie de mail</description>
    <res-ref-name>mail/Session</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.mail.Session</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

sun-jaxws.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime" version="2.0">

    <endpoint
            name="batchtestinxml"
            implementation="p3.webServiceImpl.batchWebServiceImplWS"
            url-pattern="/"/>
</endpoints>
<!--<sws:annotation-driven />-->
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="p3" />

<!-- Initialization for data source -->
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
              value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/library"/>
    <property name="username" value="P3library"/>
    <property name="password" value="toto"/>
</bean>
<bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"
              ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/> <!-- <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="notePU" /> -->
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>p3.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="authentificationDao" class= "p3.consumerDaoImpl.AuthentificationDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property> </bean>
```

webService interface

```
package p3.webService;

import p3.model.borrowing.Borrowing;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import java.util.List;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface batchWebService extends java.rmi.Remote {
@WebMethod
String batchMethod (@WebParam(name="nom") String test);
}
```

webService implementation

```
package p3.webServiceImpl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import p3.model.borrowing.Borrowing;
import p3.repository.BorrowingRepository;
import p3.service.BorrowingService;
import p3.webService.batchWebService;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "p3.webService.batchWebService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class batchWebServiceImplWS implements batchWebService {

@Autowired
private BorrowingService borrowingService;

@Override
@WebMethod
public String batchMethod(String test) {
        System.out.println(borrowingService.sendMailBorrowingExceeded());
        return "Hello toto ! " + test + " borrow : " ;
    }
}
```

publisher with endPoint

```
package p3.publisher;

import p3.webServiceImpl.batchWebServiceImplWS;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class batchWebServicePublisher {
    public static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/webService_war/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        batchWebServiceImplWS impl = new batchWebServiceImplWS();

        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(URL, impl);

        boolean status = endpoint.isPublished();
        System.out.println("Web serviceBoot disponible ? : " + status);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your application-context.xml file, Add this property
    <jpa:repositories base-package="p3.repository.BorrowingRepository"/>. Due to this missing config, Spring container is not able to find the bean.

Comment: i had your advise and my IDE tell me :
Cannot resolve package BorrowingRepository less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Spring XML model validation

| i think it doesn't read this base-package... and in my tomcat log, i always have same issue

Comment: try with "p3.repository". I think your package name BorrowingRepository is inside p3.repository. just try with it then.

Comment: you are right, and my tomcat can run now ! thank a lot ! But when i try with SOAPUI, i always have a NPE (i will examine this a little bit more)

Comment: since it solves your problem, then 'answer' should not be in comments section. so let me write this comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application-context.xml file, Add this property

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="p3.repository"/>.
```

Due to this missing config, Spring container is not able to find the bean.